# DBX: AIX equivalents of the Solaris version

Tags: c++, debugging, solaris, aix, dbx

I'm a developer who mostly programs in a solaris environment, though our code is compiled on multiple platforms, including AIX.  The most stable debugging tool I have access to on both environments is dbx, and I am quite familiar with in on the Solaris platform.
Unfortunately, dbx on AIX is very different from dbx on Solaris.
My search results haven't yielded much, and as a last ditch attempt to see if I can make any progress on this, I'm posting on StackOverflow.
I'm looking for the equivalent functionality for the following commands/procedures in dbx:

- the equivalent of the 'when' command in solaris dbx, as opposed to a simple stop
- the equivalent of the 'access' event specification (e.g. when access wa variable), where I can specify not just a variable, but an address if I prefer.
- equivalents of the 'infile', 'inclass' events

I'm not really sure if there are equivalents for any of these, but I hope there are.  My evaluation of gdb has been much better, but unfortunately, gdb does not seem to be very stable in the environment I am working in as of now.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is an active AIX community on http://ittoolbox.com. You might get some help there, but AIX!=Solaris is an understatement ;-). I'm surprised gdb is not working, the only help I can offer there is that there is very active support community for gcc (and presumably gdb). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of the 'when' on AIX:

- Set a trace on the parameter you want.
- Use addcmd to add a list of commands to the trace event.